# Running python from Java using Process Builder

Tags: java, python, beautifulsoup, processbuilder

For an existing Java code that I want to extend, I need to run a python code from within Java. I am using Process builder for this:

```
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "/directorypath/mypython.py");
   Process p=pb.start();
   BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                 InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

   BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                 InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            // read any errors from the attempted command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            System.exit(0);
        }
```

While the code runs perfectly fine from command line, in Java I get a "We need BeautifulSoup, sorry" error. As far as I understand,this means Java environment is missing some sort of libraries but then the code works perfectly from command line.

Do I need to send some environment variables? If yes, what and how?

I have 'BeautifulSoup4' installed and it is up-to-date.

Comment: Are you sure about the last argument to the command? It looks strange

Comment: They are just some parameters to be passed. This code works fine on command line.

Comment: Yes, but I believe you are passing them wrong; unless your command line _does_ look like `python /directorypath/mypython.py "-A 'A Tool for binary' -c 1"`. A `ProcessBuilder` is _not_ a shell interpreter!

Comment: Okay, but even if i pass without these arguments  [ ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "/directorypath/mypython.py")] ; I again get the same "We need BeautifulSoup, sorry" error . I edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not a definitive answer but this looks to me as a problem in the environment which this process runs in; it is probably missing some environment variables which are expected by `python` to find your "BeautifulSoup4" extension.

A `ProcessBuilder` has an `.environment()` method returning a `Map<String, String>` whose keys are the environment variables and whose values are those variables' values. **NOTE THAT MODIFYING THIS MAP ACTUALLY ALTERS THE ENVIRONMENT!** (the one of the process you will launch, that is).

Try and print your environment and compare it with what it is when you run from the command line.

Comment: On your suggestion, I ran [ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("env");] and extracted all the environment variables of linux, set them to a Map<String,String> and used this map to set the ProcessBuilder environment variables using ProcessBuilder.environment.putAll(Map<String,String>) method. I still get the same error message and Process.waitfor() returns a value 1. :(

Comment: I said to compare with the env in your command line, not from a process issued by your JVM